# Are there alternatives to ChatBlade similar in features?

Tags: c++, mmo

ChatBlade is an MMO middleware for handling client side chat in (massively) multiplayer environments. I am looking for a royalty-free, cheaper (<1k) alternative (C++ or dll preferred) that would do the same before deciding on having to spend time developing an own solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)? It's weak for transmiting binary data in-band but you may not need this on an in-game chat.

You can run [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) on your server and just embed a jabber client on your game.

There's a list of libraries implementing XMPP [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/). [gloox](http://camaya.net/gloox/) is a C++ implementation.

Comment: It's not so much the protocol we're looking for, more like the client side convenience of having chat history, configurable slash commands, fantasy language support, command stubs, item hyperlink support, etc.. It might not sound like much but these add up and having this ready would save us considerable time right now.

Comment: @konradk I think you might not find an existing

Comment: @konradk One possible option is trying to refactor an existing IRC client into a client for your game. ircII is BSD licensed and written in C. You can just run any ircd on your server. Maybe writing an in-game front end for ircII is going to be easier than writing an library that satisfy all of your needs.